# Views grouping by day with count of nodes

Tags: views

I'm trying to show a view with # of nodes by day. That one is "relatively" simple - once you find out about [this bug](http://drupal.org/node/1431780) and use the workaround ;-)

I want to show another column that shows the count of nodes that have 0 comments.
I don't think this is possible to do in views?

Comment: its simple, add a filter `Content: Comment count = 0` in views

Comment: then it wouldn't show the "count of all nodes"  ...

Comment: cant do like glossary?